# Typerrors regardless of which property I use: unshift, push, match, etc

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular feature I am working on and I keep getting a typerror.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

The feature shows a list of users from a json and displays their initials in a colored circle. Exactly like Microsoft and Android does it. Although this works, it throws a Typerror that cannot read property .match yet it does the job :/

When you click on the add button, a dialog comes up that is supposed to add the new contact to the list. That part is not working and I am afraid the typerror .push may be the culprit.

I have a Plunker that shows the error.

The error refers to this line

```
function addNewContact()
{
    $scope.contacts.push($scope.contact);

    closeDialog();
}
```

You can see it running at [PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZG3YLDkC2ngSs7KmMYxi?p=preview)

Thanks in advance

Comment: clearly `contacts` is not an array as you expect. where is it coming from? it is not being set properly

Comment: It's in contacts.json

Comment: putting a log right in the addNewContact function `console.log($scope)` shows that there is no array called contacts within it. I believe you have a scoping issue with where you're setting `contacts`

Comment: So how am I getting the data from contacts.json? It's passing through the $http service.

Comment: The JSON is loading just fine, but when you are setting it inside of $scope it is in a different scope than when you are trying to access it within `addNewContact`. you should use the `Contacts` dependency you are passing into that controller instead

Comment: I see now. Ajai in the answer explained it with a solution as well. But thank you as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$mdDialog` controller `DialogController` has different scope and you are referring to `contacts` from different scope (`myctrl`). But, you are already passing that as `Contacts` in dependency. So, you can directly push the data to `Contacts` which already has reference to your `$scope.contacts`.

```
...
function addNewContact()
{
   Contacts.push($scope.contact);
   closeDialog();
}
...
```